# ¿Cómo puedo concatenar dos arrays que contienen distintos JTextFields en java?

Tags: java, jtextfield

Os quería comentar una dudilla, a ver si alguno es  capaz de resolvèrmela!
Tengo 3 arrays distintos del tipo JTextField:

Un método me devuelve el siguiente array:

```
    JTextField Coches[] = {ford,citroen,ferrari};
```

Otro método me devuelve este:

```
    JTextField Motos[] = {kawasaki,honda};
```

Y otro método me devuelve este:

```
    JTextField trenes[]={alvia,regional,ave,trenhotel,mediadistancia};
```

Siendo ford, kawasaki, alvia etc algo del estilo:

```
    JTextField ford,kawasaki,alvia...;
    ford = new JTextField(10);//Y el resto similar.
```

¿Hay alguna forma de concatenar los 3 arrays de forma que quede algo así como

```
    JTextField Trasportes[] =
    {ford,citroen,ferrari,kawasaki,honda,alvia,regional...};
```

Posdata, no me vale esto:

```
    JTextField Transporters[] = {Coches[0],Coches[1]..motos[0]..trenes[0]..};
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Si bien es cierto que un `JTextField` se usa para mostrar texto, esto no quiere decir que vas a tener el caso que muestras ya que son objetos de Swing. Recomeindo que uses variables de tipo `String` para realizar la unión de las cadenas y luego en un `setText` de algún `JTextField` lo muestras. 
Como haría para tu problema, en un arreglo de tipo String `aux` voy poniendo elemento por elemento de cada uno de los otros arreglos, pero antes de poner busco si ya existe el elemento dentro de `aux` cosa que no se repita.
Intenta ello y coloca la implementación que haces para brindarte más ayuda.